# Confused about How to Apply Format in Java

Tags: java

I have a very basic Timer applicaiton .I need to get elapsed time between start and stop .So I am trying to format the return value .But I am getting this output

> -1421687075,731

What am I doing wrong here

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(e.getSource()==btnStartt){

            sum=0;
            count=0;
            pbShow.setMaximum(Integer.parseInt(txtenter.getText()));
            timer.start();
            now=System.currentTimeMillis();



        }
        if(e.getSource()==btnStop){

            timer.stop();
            now=System.currentTimeMillis();
            pbShow.setValue(0);
            count=0;
            Format formater=new DecimalFormat("#.#####");


        System.out.println(formater.format((end-now)/1000d));
```

Comment: One thing is that you're calculating `(end-now)`, but you're not setting `end`: you're just setting `now` again.  So I'm a little puzzled about your result.

Comment: @CPerkins Hmm the result doesn't seem very odd to me; if end isn't getting set, the result _should_ be negative.

Answer (score 1):

Your code won't compile, but based on what is there I'm going to assume your statement `now=System.currentTimeMillis();` in the second if block should be: `end=System.currentTimeMillis();`

Comment: @user3733078 It's been well over 8 minutes, what gives!?